# How to left indent a heading in python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I have three documents. One of them is created dynamically while rest are already there. Need to combine these.

```
Following is my code:
document = docx.Document()

document.add_heading("Health Authority Updates")



document.save(r'D:\test1.docx')

master = Document(r'D:\1.docx')
composer = Composer(master)

composer.append(document)
doc3 = Document(r'D:\3.docx')
composer.append(doc3)
composer.save(r"D:\combined.docx")
```

The problem is that when Health Authority Updates is printed into the file it is right indented like this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN8ou.png)

How do I left indent it?

Comment: Could you please convert your example to a Minimum Working Example (MWE) that shows your problem without us needing to guess the contents of document `1.docx`? For all we know, that document's last paragraph might simply contain the right-align in its last paragraph. Also, explicit imports (docx, docxcompose) might make it easier to find out which packages you are using.

Comment: See if it is right-indented in `test1.docx`. If not, the problem is in whatever `Composer` is, which is where I expect you'll find the problem.

Comment: It is not right indented. I added this line to left indent it though, heading.paragraph_format.left_indent = Inches(0.28)